# Delphi. Поиск Dbgrid

Tags: delphi-7

На форме находится такие компоненты как: Dbgrid,adoconnection,adoquery,datasource.
Подскажите пожалуйста,как сделать поиск лишь по одному столбцу (а не по всей таблице,например "Фамилия") через edit.

Answer (score 1):

Dbgrid тут ни при чём. Поиск ведётся по определённому полю набора данных.

А раз у Вас упоминается adoquery - делайте запрос (типа `select * from tablename where name like Пупкин`).

Результат - набор данных, содержащий записи, отвечающие запросу.

А уж этот набор может быть отображён в гриде.